# UIAlertView is causing a EXC_BAD_ACCESS and app hang

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uialertview

Ive the following code which is working fine , but when I add `UIAlertView` its start giving me `exc_bad_access` and the app hanged ,

The main idea is to show alert when timestamp dedtected ,

any tips what im doing wrong ?

```
- (void) onPayload:(PayloadEvent *) event {

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSString *header = @"[OnPayload] ";
if (event.payloadType == TYPE_IDENTIFIED) {

   if ((event.contentID != -1) && (event.timeStamp == -1)) {

        [mUI performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(Trace:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ StaticID detected: %x\t\tConfidence: %f\n", header,(int)event.contentID, event.confidence]  waitUntilDone:NO];

    }

    if ((event.timeStamp != -1) && (event.contentID == -1)) {

        [mUI performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(Trace:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Timestamp detected: %f\t\tConfidence: %f\n", header, event.timeStamp, event.confidence]  waitUntilDone:NO];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Poll" message:@"MY alert Poll" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alert show];

        [alert release];
    }

}

else if (event.payloadType == TYPE_NOT_IDENTIFIED) {

    [mUI performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(Trace:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Content not marked\n", header]  waitUntilDone:NO];

}

else if (event.payloadType == TYPE_MARKED_BUT_NOT_IDENTIFIED) {

    [mUI performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(Trace:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Content marked but not identified\n", header]  waitUntilDone:NO];

}

[event release];
[pool release];

}
```

My error appear here

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Poll" message:@"MY alert Poll" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

[alert show];  <<=====

[alert release];
```

Comment: Ah, I think it may be the release causing this. Can you try making the alert an autorelease. Or alternatively, get rid of all your memory management issues by enabling ARC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any code that changes the UI should be called from the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Poll" message:@"MY alert Poll" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
});
```

On the contrary to some comments, the view that is displaying the alert will retain the `UIAlertView` instance, so there is no need to call `autorelease` instead of `release`.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you are calling `-performSelectorOnMainThread` a few times in the same method, I imagine it's being called on a background thread. UI changes must occur on the main thread, and thus, you should be calling `[alert show];` on the main thread in order to bypass the error.

```
[alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```